# Optimize Use of Ramdisk for Eclipse Development

Tags: eclipse, ramdrive

We're developing Java/SpringSource applications with Eclipse on 32-bit Vista machines with 4GB RAM.  The OS exposes roughly 3.3GB of RAM due to reservations for hardware etc. in the virtual address space.  I came across several Ramdisk drivers that can create a virtual disk from the OS-hidden RAM and am looking for suggestions how best to use the 740MB virtual disk to speed development in our environment.

The slowest part of development for us is compiling as well as launching SpringSource dm Server.

One option is to configure Vista to swap to the Ramdisk.  That works, and noticeably speeds up development in low memory situations.  However, the 3.3GB available to the OS is often sufficient and there are many situations where we do not use the swap file(s) much.

Another option is to use the Ramdisk as a location for temporary files.  Using the Vista mklink command, I created a hard link from where the SpringSource dm Server's work area normally resides to the Ramdisk.  That significantly improves server startup times but does nothing for compile times.  There are roughly 500MB still free on the Ramdisk when the work directory is fully utilized, so room for plenty more.

What other files/directories might be candidates to place on the Ramdisk?  Eclipse-related files?  (Parts of) the JDK?

Is there a free/open source tool for Vista that will show me which files are used most frequently during a period of time to reduce the guesswork?

Comment: PS - Yes this would all be solved by moving to a 64-bit OS, but that's not a viable option at the moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I did

Moved to the Ramdisk:

- JDK (deleted some unnecessary files e.g. demos, src.zip)
- Eclipse plugins directory
- SpringSource work directory
- SpringSource library directories

There's a neat trick that lets you move folders (or files for that matter) to the virtual disk without making a single change to configuration.

1. Copy the folder to the Ramdisk
2. Rename the original folder (I added -COPY to the end)
3. Use the **mklink /J** command to make a link from the place on disk where the directory used to be before you renamed it to where you copied it on the Ramdisk

For example:

```
cd C:\Dev\Apps
Xcopy jdk R:\jdk\ /s
ren jdk jdk-COPY
mklink /J jdk R:\jdk
```

The Ramdisk I selected has an option to persist state upon system shutdown (assuming there is no crash).  I elected to move only relatively static files onto the Ramdisk, so once I have one good reboot, I should always find my Ramdisk in the state I need it.

On pre-Vista machines you can substitute junction from SysInternals for mklink.

Comment: maybe it could work also with http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM and then tweak the paths of jre in Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

Comment: Thanks for these instructions. It really helped me to speed my Eclipse. The only problem is whenever I restart my machine I have redo all these steps. Is there any way to create a persistent RAM disk across retstarts or shutdowns. I am using Imdisk to create a Ramdisk on my machine.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav: Primo Ramdisk is a ramdisk product that persists your RAM disk to the hard disk.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav: Another thought... if you kept the -COPY versions of directories on your hard drive, you could write a batch file that copies the appropriate directories over to the RAM disk upon bootup.  That would allow you to work with Imdisk.  I do really like the Primo one though.  Not very expensive and quite flexible.

Comment: Hi @EricJ. how do you move your `plugins` directory to ramdisk or any directory outside of `eclipse` directory?

Comment: @fuzzybee: You physically locate them on a different drive and create a symbolic link where eclipse expects to find them that points to the different drive.  Steps to do that are shown in my answer.

Comment: @andrejs82: That depends on too many factors go give a specific answer. The slower your hard disk is, the better the performance gain. Note you may find that some third party disk cache solutions give a similar performance boost but are much simpler to setup. I use Primo Cache on an older laptop and it helps quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to move your Eclipse workspace into a ram disk. I am pretty sure neither javac, nor Eclipse compiler are using any temp files, so it goes straight from the *.java files to *.class files plus copying resource files from source location into a target folder.

Another alternative you may want to consider is to use a solid state drive (SSD). You are going to see a significant performance improvements in many areas that are heavily reading and writing files from disk.

Comment: My concern with moving the workspace onto the ram disk is the potential loss of work in the event of an outage.  Moving to an SSD is not an option at the moment, but something we are looking at int he future (probably the same time we move to 64-bit OS :-)

Comment: You can deal with a loss of work by having your workspace code under version control. Something like Subversion or Git would allow you to quickly push changes to a persistent storage.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the SoftPerfect RAM Disk software. I installed the JDK, Eclipse, Maven, Gradle, and Ant on it. Also my workspace, my development git repositories and the local Maven repository (all downloaded dependencies) are on the RAM drive. I also created a "user home" directory on the RAM drive and I changed eclipse.ini to point to this new "user home" directory. Performance has improved dramatically and Eclipse now starts up under 10 seconds. I documented my approach here:

http://www.whizu.org/articles/how-to-install-eclipse-on-a-ramdrive.whizu

Answer (score 0):

I don't think move JDK and plugins folder to the ramdisk is a good solution for this case, since most time these IO is not the bottleneck for eclipse. I tried with your solution, and found that the workspace.metadata folder should be move to the ramdisk, that could help the build and execute speed. And if possible, you should move all your workspace folder under the ramdisk, and use some version control to ensure the data safe. Good luck.

Comment: Turns out moving JDK & plugins made a HUGE difference for me... On the other hand, I would be very worried about moving my workspace onto the RAM disk.  One crash or power outage could wipe quite a bit of work away.