# Eclipse 3.5 load time and other performance improvement

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.5

I am using eclipse 3.5 Galileo enterprise edition for development of java standalone applications.I have disabled few plugins in startup.Still i am not quite happy with the IDE performance.Are there any more feature disable or configurations to make it work faster?
Please tel me if further information is required to answer this,i will update the question:)

Comment: Did you use an optimized eclipse.ini? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve performance by tuning your eclipse.ini file. Here's an example file with some tuning options added:

```
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20080819.jar
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs 
-Xms256m 
-Xmx512m 
-XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+StringCache
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:+UseLargePages
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=4m
-XX:AllocatePrefetchLines=1
-XX:AllocatePrefetchStyle=1
-Dide.gc=true
```

I would do some research and testing to work out which settings work best for you. There's some information [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t20732.html) that might help with this.

Answer (score 2):

I created a RAM disk and placed key files such as the JDK and Eclipse plugin directory on the RAM disk.  That improved Eclipse 3.5 performance very significantly.

You can [read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838018/optimize-use-of-ramdisk-for-eclipse-development).