# Eclipse refresh taking too long

Tags: eclipse, build, tdd

I am doing TDD on a large Java project in eclipse and am finding it frustrating because every time I run a test I have to wait 30 seconds+ for eclipse to compile and refresh. I estimate that 80%+ of that time is spent refreshing.

Is there a way I can drastically reduce the amount of refreshing it is doing? I have looked at server other similar questions but I could not see anything that helps.

One way I reduced the compile refresh time was to split the unit tests and code into separate projects. There are 4,700 classes in the src project and 300 in the tests. I am running eclipse 3.5.1 on Java 1.6.0_17-b04 (eclipse.vm). My computer is running windows xp with 3.1 gigs of usable ram. The only plugin I have installed is subclipse.

Comment: Can you break down what you do during each iteration? Like:

1. Write a failing test.
2. Project > Build Automatically is checked, so I wait for the test to compile.
3. Run the test to confirm that it fails.
4. Write code to fix the failing test.
5. Wait for the project to auto-build.
6. Run the test to confirm the fix actually fixed the test.

I'm having a hard time understanding how running a test is triggering a compile. Also, can you be more specific about what needs to be refreshed each time?

Comment: @Rob Heiser - To test the build / refresh speed I make a minor change to a src file, like change a static final number to an incorrect value, then run a unit test.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be memory related - I first tried setting -Xmx1000m in eclipse.ini, then 
-Xmn100m
-Xms512m
-Xmx700m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=400M
-XX:MaxPermSize=500M
as was suggested in another question. Neither had any effect.

Comment: Try using the server VM too (not sure if Eclipse does this by default). -server in eclipse.ini. Also, make sure you have any projects you're not working on closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there were build errors in the project that did not affect the tests or the code I was working on but were there none the less. When I resolved all build errors in my eclipse workspace the issue with long refreshes when away. This was tested on eclipse 3.5 and 3.6.

I feel a little foolish now :(, but from what I have seen professionally there are a lot of people with lingering IDE build issues.

Answer (score 5):

I significantly increased the performance of Eclipse under 32-bit Windows by creating a RAM disk using the portion of the OS-unadressable memory as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838018/optimize-use-of-ramdisk-for-eclipse-development).

If you have (or can increase to) 4GB of ram from your current 3.1 the same approach will quite possibly help you.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the post I made here about eclipse.ini options: [Eclipse IDE speed sluggish on Snow Leopard Macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204173/eclipse-ide-speed-sluggish-on-snow-leopard-macbook/2204456#2204456). Some of these might help you as they can adjust Eclipse environment settings (allocate more memory, etc). Also consider migrating your workspace to a faster disk :)

Comment: The b04 is the build number, not the beta version.

Answer (score 1):

This could definitely be memory related.  See one of:

- [Eclipse memory settings when getting "Java Heap Space" and "Out of Memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334102/eclipse-memory-settings-when-getting-java-heap-space-and-out-of-memory)
- http://blog.xam.dk/?p=58

They both give a good overview on Eclipse memory configuration, which I think will at least help with this issue.